# How does alchemy work in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

One of the things I loved about Morrowind and Oblivion was the Alchemy ability; the ability to make potions.

How does alchemy work in Skyrim? Is it the same as Oblivion?

Comment: Question re-opened, and outdated comments purged! ♪

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found some information about Alchemy on the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy_%28Skyrim%29)

According to the Wiki, Alchemy has been confirmed as a skill in Skyrim. Alchemy will govern the ability of the player to make more potent potions and poisons.

Instead of carrying around the tools (retort, alembic, etc) players will instead utilize labs or alchemy stations throughout the game.

Each possible ingredient in Skyrim has been confirmed to have four possible properties. These are unknown until the player either individually eats an ingredient or successfully mixes a potion/poison.

Alchemy ingrediants can be found throughout Skyrim growing in the wild as well as in towns. They may also be found through certain shopkeepers.